# Using a CASE Expression in the Default Value

Tags: t-sql, syntax, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a script for my dba to run. In development I have added a new column to an existing table. When I run the following script I have separated the ALTER and UPDATE on my table. I was trying to combine the statements into one.  Any suggestions? Not sure if this is possible or I am on the right track. Thanks in advance!

Current Script that is working fine:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and  
Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
begin
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
ADD NewColumn BIT NULL
DEFAULT 0
end


if exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and Object_ID  = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
begin
UPDATE dbo.TableA
SET Newcolumn = CASE WHEN CodeID IN ('A','B') THEN 1 END
WHERE CodeID IN ('A','B')
end
```

Trying to combine the ALTER and UPDATE into one:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
begin
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
ADD NewColumn BIT NULL
DEFAULT case CodeID
WHEN 'A' THEN 1
WHEN 'B' THEN 1
end
```

I get the following error:
The name "CodeID" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this, but I noticed you used different syntax for the CASE statement in the working script and the non-working script.  Try this:

```
 if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
 begin
     ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
     ADD NewColumn BIT NULL
     DEFAULT case WHEN CodeID = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 end
```

But it would not surprise me if you can't reference another column in the default for a column.  For example, what happens when you insert a new record without specifying a value for `NewColumn`?  At insert time, `CodeID` doesn't have a value because the row doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i did some more digging around. The following solves my problem:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and  
Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
begin
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
ADD NewColumn BIT NULL
DEFAULT 0 with Values
end


if exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'NewColumn' and Object_ID    = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
begin
UPDATE dbo.TableA
SET Newcolumn =  1 WHERE CodeID IN ('A','B')
end
```

I was over complicating things. In order to combine the update I would have to try and add a trigger.  This works for what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: So now every time you insert or update a row, you're going to have to run that additional update?

Comment: No. The script is just being run once to sync production with dev.